# Print Multiple Reports on Client Side with SSRS

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We have developed an application in ASP.Net and SilverLight.
We are using SSRS 2008 Reports.
We need to print the reports on Client Side.

There is a report to print Invoice with Invoice No. as Parameter.

My Client needs to print this report for multiple Invoices.
He wants to Select Multiple Invoice Nos and click print button, and without any preview, the reports should print for all Invoices selected.

So the single report will be printed multiple times with different parameters

Is this possible? If yes, Please guide.

Comment: You could change your report to accept multiple invoices as parameter, then generate 1 page per invoice. So then you can print 1 report but every page contains a different invoice. But to print without popup, this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new report that has a multi-valued InvoiceNo parameter, and a List in the body of the report.   The List will generate one list item for every InvoiceNo chosen in the parameter.   Inside the list is a sub-report that calls your existing single-invoice report.   You pass the invoice number from the list item to the subreport.   Put a page break between the items in the list.   Then you will have a single report with one page per invoice.